# AppCenter Swift Package Manager Dependency import failed

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been trying to add the AppCenter library in my project using the SPM, the package is downloaded properly but XCode keeps saying that it can't be found.
Here is the link of the Git : https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple

This the package description of how i intended to import the dependency:
[image]

Here is the error that XCode keeps showing:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you should use `.product` to add deps `AppCenterAnalytics`, `AppCenterCrashes` and `AppCenterDistribute` separately.

Full answer is here: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple/issues/2294#issuecomment-826768598